# Android empty Linear layout contents

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

H have multiple `TextViews` inside an `LinearLayout`. Now I want to delete this text view in java. The views are generated dynamically. How can I empty all contents inside this `LinearLayout`?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/myid">

    <TextView .../>
    <TextView .../>
    <TextView .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can use this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myid);
ll.removeAllViews();
```